# Linear Algebra, Least Squares and Error (Matlab)

Tags: linear-algebra, matlab

> "Let $A$ be a $4 \times 4$ random matrix with rank $2$ (check that its rank is $2$). Let $b$ be a random vector in $\mathbb R^4$.
>
> Check that the system $Ax = b$ is inconsistent and then find a least squares solution $x_0$ of $Ax = b$ (is this solution unique?).
>
> Compute the error vector $b-Ax_0$. Check that this error vector is perpendicular to the
>   column space of $A$.
>
> Compute the error is the length $\|b - Ax_0\|$. Check that this error is minimized for the
>   least squares solution by computing $\|b - Ax\|$ for several random vectors $x$ and seeing that it is larger than the error."

So far I have:

```
A = rand(4,2)*rand(2,4);
rank(A);
b=rand(4,1);
C=inv(A)*b;
x = (inv(A'*A))*A'*b;
E = b-A*x;
D = norm(E);
```

The first three lines define $A$ and $b$ and prove the rank is 2. `C` is intended to prove $Ax=b$ is inconsistent (it returns a strange answer). `x` should be the least squares solution, this apparently is not unique because of the last question, but I don't know how else to find an `x`. E is the error vector; I do not know how to check it's perpendicular to the column space of $A$. `D` is the length of the error vector; I do not know how to find other `x`'s to test.

Comment: Holy everloving... please *please* **please** use `C=A\b;` and `x = (A'*A)\(A'*b);` (and even this second one could be improved upon!), instead of `C=inv(A)*b;` and `x = (inv(A'*A))*A'*b;`!

Comment: @J.M. or better leave it to MATLAB with `linsolve` ;)

Comment: @percusse: I like backslash more than `linsolve()`, but whatever floats your boat, no? ;)

Comment: @J.M. `inv(A'*A)` is bad, but `inv(A)`, provided it exists, is not necessarily bad. `A\b` is no better if there are multiple right hand sides to solve for. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/a/35150369/517835 .

Answer (score 1):

$E$ will be perpendicular to the column space of $A$ if and only if it is perpendicular to each of the columns of $A$, so if you know how to check whether two vectors are perpendicular, that part should be easy. As for how to find other values of $x$ to test, the problem statement calls for "several random vectors $x$", so presumably you just generate several random vectors (of the appropriate number of components) and test them.